# Bypassing proxy for loopback/locahost

Tags: networking, proxy, firewall, localhost

I am developing a web application where in I am running a webserver at localhost:3000 and my app is deployed on the same.

Access to this URL through a web browser works fine because there is an option in the browser to say that I want to bypass the proxy for localhost/127.0.0.1. If I don't use this , the request when routed through the proxy is blocked by the campus firewall(I am a student).

When I programmatically try to make requests to localhost/127.0.0.1, the firewall like above kicks in and I am served an error message. The same happens when I use

```
$ curl http://localhost:3000
```

Could you let me know how I can configure my system such that bypassing the proxy for localhost/127.0.0.1 works on a system wide scale rather than being an application specific setting(my web browser as mentioned above).

Answer (score 0):

My module I was using to make this http request(https://github.com/intridea/oauth2) was picking up the proxy setting from the current shell environment. Setting the shell environment variables, `http_proxy` and `HTTP_PROXY`, to an empty string helped